# LINQ query maps dates incorrectly

Tags: c#, linq

My query looks like so:

```
using (var ctx = new PCLvsCompContext())
{
    var brokerId = broker?.Id;
    var symbolId = company?.Id;

    var result = (from t in ctx.TradeHistoryJoineds
            where t.TradeDate >= fromDate
                && t.TradeDate <= toDate
                && (brokerId == null || t.BrokerId == brokerId)
                && (symbolId == null || t.SymbolId == symbolId)
            select t).OrderBy(x => x.TradeDate).ThenBy(x => x.BrokerName).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

As an example, I run this query with dates like fromDate March-01-2017 toDate March-31-2017. I then captured the generated sql in SQL profiler that this query produces and ran it in SQL management studio.  The output was as expected where for each weekday, each company has some trades.  The query is based off of a view which casts all dates to "datetime" so that excel can parse them as dates correctly.  However, when I put a breakpoint at "return result" and inspect the dates, all but 2 of the dates are March-1-2017.  This is incorrect, the query result in SQL manager shows trades for almost every weekday in March (which is correct).

What is going on here?  Why is Linq losing its mind?

Comment: Does the query in SQL manager and the one from linq return the same number of results?

Comment: you mention Excel, but you also mention SSMS; what is the backend here? have you checked that you're connecting where you *think* you're connecting? with some very niche exceptions, queries *generally* do the same thing via ADO.NET and SSMS. Also, are you sure you aren't just looking at the first matches? we would *expect* the March-1st records to be first, for example (because of the `OrderBy`)

Comment: What is the value of `toDate`?

Comment: Could it be that TradeDate is UTC but fromDate, toDate are localtime?
Are you relying on conversion from string to datetime?
What is the language of the database compared to your operating system?

Answer (score 1):

Although based on the results I cannot see exactly how you would end up with those results, it is very common that you could be dealing with a `DateTime` timezone issue. I suspect that perhaps you saved your dates to the database using a `DateTime` object from say `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.UtcNow`. So at that point in time and based on the machine it was called on it would be based on the timezone and datelight savings of that machine.

A `DateTime` object should not be used as it can relate to the region of the SQL database, the region of the server making this LINQ call and so the two regions could be on different timezones.

Instead you should always use `DateTimeOffset`.

If you cannot do that for some reason, then double-check your dates toDate and fromDate and do:

```
var utcToDate = toDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'");

var utcFromDate = toDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'");
```

Which gives something like this if it was run on 3rd April 2018 at 22:56.

```
2018-04-03T22:56:57.740Z
```

You would then also need to make sure when you save any date to the SQL backing store that you do ToUniversalTime() firstly. You can check your SQL tables directly with a normal SQL query and they should be stored in the database as the same UTC string format as above, and then the comparison should be obvious to whether it is valid.

> However I would strongly recommend changing all your DateTime calls and gets to `DateTimeOffset`. The only time to use `DateTime` in majority of cases is for the final display to a user.

Comment: Thanks for this great summary.  Currently all the databases in the company I work for use straight up Dates so I will look into how hard it would be to migrate to offsets sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions.  For those who are familiar with linq, EF and views this may seem like a stupid oversight, but I will post my shame for others in case this happens to them since the cause and the resulting behavior are not immediately obviously linked (as can be seen by all the suggestions, none of which actually point to the answer).

When you are querying a view using linq and Entity Framework, you apparently must have a column called 'Id', otherwise Entity Framework can't distinguish any of the rows from one another and simply makes some sort of duplication that I can't quite decipher (all the rows were unique based on their data even without an Id column, so I can't quite figure out why this is necessary).

So by adding an the TradeId with an 'Id' alias to the view, then Entity Framework seemed to return to sanity and map the data as expected.